# Validate text fields based on checkbox value - jQuery validation

Tags: php, jquery

I have a list of items and each item has a checkbox attached to it. I am currently using the jQuery form and validation plugin. I want to use it such that only if the user checks the checkbox , the text fields associated with that checkbox is validated else no validation is required.

Following is the code for demo

```
<form action='feeddatabase.php' method=post id='feedlisting'>
<input type=submit value='Submit!' name=submit>

<table border=2>
    <input type=text name='title1' size=100 style='display:none' value="Babes with curves are the new rage in Bollywood">
 <tr>
<td rowspan="9"><input type='checkbox' class='article_check'  name='selectArticle[]'   value=1 /></td>
<td colspan="2"><h3><u><a href='http://www.santabanta.com/cinema.asp?pid=47880'>Babes with curves are the new rage in Bollywood</a></u></h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Url</b></td>
 <td><input type=text  class='article_req_info' name='url1' size=100 value='http://www.santabanta.com/cinema.asp?pid=47880'>
                    <input type=text style='display:none' name='blogurl1' size=100 value='http://www.santabanta.com/cinema.asp'>
                    <input type=text style='display:none' name='blogtitle1' size=100 value="Latest Bollywood news, Movie Review and Previews">
                    <input type=text style='display:none' name='blogfeedurl1' size=100 value='http://www.santabanta.com/rss/cinema.asp?cat=Mirch Masala'></td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><b>Author</b></td>
 <td><input type=text  name='author1' size=100 value=''></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td><b>Date</b></td><td><input type=text name='date1' size=100 value='2011-7-08'> </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><b>Desc</b></td>
  <td><input type=text name='desc1' size=100 value="The curve is more powerful than the sword. And the one time sex goddess should know this from her experience...">
                    <input type=text  style='display:none' name='html_content1'  value='The curve is more powerful than the sword. And the one time sex goddess should know this from her experience...'><br></td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><b>Featured</b></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='featuredArticle1' value=1 /></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><b>Category</b></td>
 <td><select name="category1">
<option value="Technology"  >Technology</option>
<option value="Social" >Social</option>
<option value="Entertainment"selected >Entertainment</option>
<option value="Gaming"  >Gaming</option>
<option value="News"  >News</option>
<option value="Sports"  >Sports</option>
<option value="Videos"  >Videos</option></select></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><u>Tags: </u></td>
 <td><input type=text name='tag1' size=100 value='new rage,curves,babes'></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><u>Images for the post from Content/Google/Default</u></td>
 <td><input type=radio name="group1" checked value='http://media.santabanta.com/newsite/cinemascope/images/sonakshi24_big.jpg' \>
 </td>
 </tr>

 </table>
</form>
```

The jquery am using is as follows

```
<html> 
<head> 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery.loady.js"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">

 /* $("#loader").loady({
                    url: "sharer.php"
                }); */ 

$(document).ready(function() { 
    // bind form using ajaxForm 

        /* $(this).loady({
                    url: "sharer.php"
                }); */


        $('.article_check').click(function() {

             rules: {
                article_info: {
                    required: true,

                };  
            }
            });

});
</script>
 </head>
 <body>

</body>

</html>
```

Please corect me if i am wrong somewhere...

EDIT:

now am using the below script

```
 <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#feedlisting").validate();
  }); 



 function countChecked() {
  var n = $("input[name='selectArticle[]']:checked").length;
  var v = $("input[name='selectArticle[]']:checked").val();

  if(v)
  {
  alert(v);
  alert("url"+v);
  $("#url"+v).addClass('required url');
  }
  else
  {

$("#url"+v).removeClass('required url');
  }
  $("div").text(n + (n <= 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" + " value :" + v);
}
//countChecked();
$("input[name='selectArticle[]']:checkbox").click(countChecked);
</script>
```

Its working great except that when I uncheck, the removeClass thing isnt working. When I check it dynamically adds the 'required url' class but when I uncheck, doesnt remove it. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of options:
1. [add a custom rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) for vaildation of the text fields; your validation function would check the checkboxes' values and only then validate the text fields.
2. add an `onchange` event to the checkboxes, which would add / remove the class `'required'` from the relevant text fields (remember that validation rules can also be defined in the markup using class attributes)

**EDIT**
in response to your question, here's a simple solution:

I'm assuming that you have a static (=known in advance) list of textfields you want to change. for example- if those fields are `txtName` and `txtAddress`, your code could be something like:

```
$("#checkBox").change(function () { 
     if ($("#checkBox").val() {
          //if checkbox is checked- add the 'required' class
          $("#txtName").addClass('required');
          $("#txtAddress").addClass('required');
     }
     else {
          //if checkbox is unchecked- remove the 'required' class
          $("#txtName").rmeoveClass('required');
          $("#txtAddress").removeClass('required');
     }
});
```

Comment: ok...the onchange event seems plausible at the moment as i am able to fetch the value of the checkbox fetched.This value represents some id. Say the checkbox i checked has value 1, then all the input textfields under that checkbox has names like title1,headline1,dw1...etc....   so how do i code the onchange event such that i can add 'required' attributes to fields attached to those checkboxes only. Am sorry am neww to javascript and jQuey...not good at coding in this language :(

Comment: Thanks a lot sJhonny....just rectify me if am wrong. i have a lis tof known text fields and dropdowns,checkboxes and select fields. Just that each set has a dynamic name...Could i modiy the code above like this.. $("#txtName"+$("#checkBox").val()).addClass('required')   ??

Comment: you could, but i'd hardly recommend it. if you know the full name of your control- why not use it? if all fields are known in advance- why not name them in advance? and btw- i'd really advise against using numbers in variable / control names.

Comment: actually the scenario is, i know there are going to be max to max 10 articles to select (checkboxes) per page. Each of these articles will have 3 text fields. eg: checkbox1 will have txt_fld1_1 txt_fld2_1 txt_fld3_1 and checkbox2 will have txt_fld1_2,txt_fld2_2,txt_fld3_2 and so on. At run time user can select any checkbox and depending on that value of checkbox I wud know which suffix to use to describe those fields. Just check the code i posted in my original question, you will realize my scenario. You have a better solution for this scenario? Thanks for the advice mate :)

Comment: watch my EDIT in the original question. got it to partially work but need your help